# Remove specific element on list with math logic in scala

Tags: scala, list, math, logic

If I have this list:

```
val aList =  List(1,1,1,3,4),List(3,3,5,6,7),List(7,7,7,6,7),List(2,3,3,2,6)
```

How do I update the list by eliminating non-duplicated numbers on the first head of the `List`? so the result should be:

`val aRes = List(1,1,1), List(3,3), List(7,7,7)`

`List(2,3,3,2,6)` should be removed also since we don't have 3 at the head of the list. My expectation for the result was:

`val aRes = aList(1) map {case List(i) => List(aList.groupBy(_(1))}`

But it seems not valid for this logic.

beside that, I also need to translate those result values to another list member:

```
val aScore = List(
      /*score for 1*/ List(0, 0, 1500, 2500, 5000),
      /*score for 2*/ List(0, 0, 500, 1000, 2000),
      /*score for 3*/ List(0, 50, 100, 200, 500),
      /*score for 4*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150),
      /*score for 5*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150),
      /*score for 6*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150),
      /*score for 7*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150)
    )
```

`val score = ???`

so from above `aList` result, the score must be `1500+50+50 = 1600` as result from `1*3=>1500`, `3*2=>50` and `7*3=>50`

Comment: Have you had a go at the code and need further help?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to split them with `x.groupBy` and `x.splitAt` but it seems not working for this logic.

Comment: Maybe, ask your professor for some tips?

Comment: @Dima Thanks for all the notifications, I won't ask some other question like this since I feel bad for anyone who answered my question but got -1 from you.

Comment: @DedenBangkit I have looked at the previous ten questions your asked ... Don't feel bad for people I downvoted, the'll be fine. Better think about yourself. One day you will run into a problem for which you couldn't just lift a solution off the good folks on SO. What are you going to do then?

Comment: @Dima : ) thanks for your advice, but thats what I like about stackoverflow, when I have downvote until I coulnd't ask anymore, I could try to answer other people questions, something like karma. If you are good to others, you also could get another help from the others. I wish I could answer more (like you do) than asking lot of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to return something if there are duplicates, and nothing if not, so make a function that returns an `Option`:

```
def f(xs: List[Int]) = xs match {
  case x0 :: x1 :: _ if x0 == x1 => Some(xs.takeWhile(_ == x0))
  case _ => None
}
```

Then `flatMap` your list to that to get rid of the optiony bits:

```
aList.flatMap(f)
```

For the second part:

```
def getScore(xs: List[Int]) = aScore(xs.head - 1)(xs.size - 1)
```

So just map and sum the elements. In total:

```
aList.flatMap(f).map(getScore).sum   
// result = 1600
```

Comment: I just realized that I could put None for the result then flat them all.  Your logic is brilliant. Thank you very much!

Comment: you can reduce two `match` expressions  to one: 

def f(xs: List[Int]) = xs match {
    case x0 :: x1 :: _ if x0 == x1 => Some(xs.takeWhile(_ == x0))
    case _ => None
  }

Comment: @n4to4 Good thinking - that's definitely more elegant. Will update answer.

Comment: @n4to4 you have good answer! Omg so many brilliant people here. By the way, why does flatMap for List takes only the second parameter [B]? not Both [A,B]

Comment: @DedenBangkit the parameter A, representing the element type, has already been defined by the class `List[A]`

Comment: BTW we could also equivalently write `def f(xs: List[Int]) = Option(xs) collect { case x0 :: x1 :: _ if x0 == x1 => xs.takeWhile(_ == x0) }`

Comment: Thank you @LuigiPlinge, you are the best! I've updated your answer with other alternatives you gave.

Answer (score 3):

```
object parseData {
  val inputList = List(List(1,1,1,3,4),List(3,3,5,6,7),List(7,7,7,6,7),List(2,3,3,2,6))
  val aScore = List(
    /*score for 1*/ List(0, 0, 1500, 2500, 5000),
    /*score for 2*/ List(0, 0, 500, 1000, 2000),
    /*score for 3*/ List(0, 50, 100, 200, 500),
    /*score for 4*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150),
    /*score for 5*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150),
    /*score for 6*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150),
    /*score for 7*/ List(0, 10, 50, 100, 150)
  )

  def isDuplicated(aList: List[Int]): Boolean = aList.head == aList.tail.head

  def getRidOfNonDuplicates(aList: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    val opList = ListBuffer(aList.head)
    def loop(aList: List[Int], opList: ListBuffer[Int]): Unit = {
      if (aList.tail == Nil) return
      if (aList.head == aList.tail.head) opList += aList.tail.head
      loop(aList.tail, opList)
    }
    loop(aList, opList)
    opList.toList
  }

  def printaScoreValue(aList: List[Int]): Unit = println(aScore(aList.head - 1)(aList.length - 1))

  val outputList = inputList.filter(isDuplicated(_))
  val opList = ListBuffer.empty[List[Int]]
  for (aList <- outputList)
    opList += getRidOfNonDuplicates(aList)
  opList.foreach(printaScoreValue(_))
}
```

gives

```
1500
50
50
```

Comment: You have complete and correct answer for the logic. But, I need to know which one is faster for removing non-duplicates value to new List, since other answer also correct.

Comment: Yes! And also, please complete proof that your algorithm works, and scientific benchmarks demonstrating performance! The OP is way to busy to waste his valuable time on shit like this. The deadline is approaching fast, so you better get to work fast!
I have -1'd your answer, because I think, questions like this greatly reduce the quality of content of SO, and answering them encourages such behavior.

Comment: @Dima Why not flag the question than penalizing and discouraging answerers? I get your point and I don't mind that my +1 was taken away. Discouraging answerers will also create another problem, don't you think?

Comment: @shaktimaan no, I don't :) Discouraging answers to questions like this is exactly my goal ...

Comment: @Dima I think it would be more helpful if we guide the new users towards relevant discussions like this - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions than being hostile with snarky comments.

Comment: @shaktimaan Yes, You don't deserve any -1 for aswering my question, so sorry bro. Dima is right, the problem is my question. You could flag my question and report to moderator. Thanks for your notification.

Comment: Dima is not right, as your linked meta page shows: "It is okay to ask about homework." "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines.". Have an upvote from me!

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Right back at ya! :)

Comment: @LuigiPlinge asking about homework is not at all the same as asking someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

My first stab was:

```
scala> val ls =  List(List(1,1,1,3,4),List(3,3,5,6,7),List(7,7,7,6,7),List(2,3,3,2,6))
ls: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1, 3, 4), List(3, 3, 5, 6, 7), List(7, 7, 7, 6, 7), List(2, 3, 3, 2, 6))

scala> ls map { 
  _ groupBy identity filter { case (i, is) => is.length > 1 } flatMap { _._2 } 
}
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1), List(3, 3), List(7, 7, 7, 7), List(2, 2, 3, 3))
```

But as you can see, it not quite what you want. I think the next one nails it:

```
scala> ls map { l => 
         val (h,t) = (l.head, l.tail) 
         h :: t.takeWhile( _ == h ) 
       } filter { _.length > 1 }
res7: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1), List(3, 3), List(7, 7, 7))
```

But notice, it is not going to work if `List.empty` is an element of the outer list.